# Prepared statements ortography

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

[Prepared Statements as explained in Programming with Tony](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) reason to put arguments outside the SQL string.

So my question is:

1. How important is lowercase UPPERCASE in an MySQL? (SELECT v select; AND v and)
2. How important is it to "backtick" away the names? (SELECT 'name' FROM 'table' WHERE variable = :variable) [I have NO FREAKin' clue how to add backticks here]
3. Should I ever put integers/numbers in as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.- How important is lowercase UPPERCASE in an MySQL? (SELECT v select; AND v and)

SQL commands are not case sensitive. It's kind of common practice to uppercase them so they're easier to spot, but it isn't mandatory.

> 2.- How important is it to "backtick" away the names? (SELECT 'name' FROM 'table' WHERE variable = :variable)

You must escape object names when they are reserved words or contain special characters (such as spaces). Otherwise, it's entirely optional.

The backtick syntax is MySQL-only. Other databases use double quotes or square brackets.

> [I have NO FREAKin' clue how to add backticks here]

Use the "Code Sample" toolbar button:

[image: Code Sample]

> 3.- Should I ever put integers/numbers in as string?

If you do, MySQL will have to cast them to numbers. You won't notice a performance penalty but there's no specific reason to use strings. It's as redundant as doing this in PHP:

```
echo "$name";
```

Additionally, you editor's syntax highlighter will not tell numbers apart:

[image: Number as String]

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

1. Yes you can use both the cases(uppercase,lowercase).
2. When you use some reserved words for mysql as column name you have to use backticks.
3. Yes you can put integers/numbers in as string.

Comment: 1. is there a speed increase for using UPPERCASE over lowercase? I suppose I need to know, if MYSQl will reparse the statement to add the backticks or not?

Comment: @user2075899: None whatsoever.

Comment: @user2075899 No there is no speed increase for using uppercase over lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use UPPER CASE because it makes it easier to see what's an SQL keyword and what is not.
2. Make it a habit to always use backticks, for example if you have a column named 'Dec' and don't use a backtick on it within a query, you'll get an error because DEC() is an SQL function.
3. Absolutely. SQL automatically converts a numerical string into a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

1. I personally think that uppercase helps distinguish SQL keywords from table names and column names.
2. Backticks help because at some point or another, you might end up with an identifier that contains special characters or is a reserved MySQL keyword. To use an identifier or a special character, you must quote it with backticks.
3. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> How important is lowercase UPPERCASE in an MySQL? (SELECT v select; AND v and)

It is important to use uppercase, however for readability purpose only.

> How important is it to "backtick" away the names?

it depends.
For the hardcoded identifiers they are optional, but for the dynamical ones they are **obligatory**, as you cannot know which value will be passed. Of course you have to escape backticks inside passed value by doubling them as well.

> Should I ever put integers/numbers in as string?

It depends.
In general there is no difference.
And in case you're using ugly mysqli with dynamical binding, it is easier to bind all variables as "s".
But when using PDO, one have to be careful with setting LIMIT parameters as strings - PDO in emulation mode will break SQL.